# Html video not playing when loaded to the server

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I have a short 8 second video I want to play before entering the site. I'm using autoplay (yes I know that autoplay is not recommended but I want it for a specific reason, it's 8 seconds and there is no sound) and then a delayed page redirect to the main page. I'm using this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <body>
  <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay poster="/assets/Videoposter.jpg">
    <source src="./assets/Video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="./assets/Video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
    <source src="./assets/Video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  </video>
 </body>'

'<script>
 var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location='./article.html'
    }, 8300);
</script>
```

When I try it locally it works but as soon as I upload it to server the page loads but is blank and then after 8300ms it redirects to the other page.

In my assets folder I have the 3 forms of the video and the poster image. I've tried ./assets/ and /assets. I've also tried it without the body tags.  Can anyone point out why it is not playing. Thanks.

Comment: what is your server url ? it might help!.
also i some times i have this issue with "Capital" files names, maybe make sure they all small letters named in your server and call them in your html in small letters.
and it does redirect because you have a redirect call after 8.3 seconds down there :|

Comment: Does a direct link work? `<source src="https://yoursite.com/assets/Video.mp4" />` ...Notice no `type` or `codecs`? Also test on Chrome if possible and check your debugger console for any errors which might give you some clue towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Using a direct link for the src worked and decapitalizing the names worked.  I also had an underscore number (video_2.mp4) and I took away the underscore which I think helped. In short lesson learned 'keep the names as simple as possible'.